# Is there way to detect surface area of nanoparticle by electrochemical technique?

Tags: electrochemistry, surface-chemistry

I want to know other than SEM is there any other technique or instrument to detect the surface area of particle esp eletrochemical way.

Comment: if you have a reference point, you can either titrate some surface groups or measure change in concentration of some dissolved compound due to adsorption on particles' surface.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic light scattering is commonly used to measure nanoparticle size: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_light_scattering

Whether you can measure this sort of thing electrochemically depends a lot on the type of nanoparticle. Conductive nanoparticles, you might be able to estimate the surface area by measuring adsorptive behaviours of various things, like CO for Pt and Pd: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1388248113000933 Non-conductive particles might be measured by how they impede diffusion to a surface. Electrochemical techniques could suffer from problems related to the shapes of the nanoparticles, as well.

The most straightforward ways of examining the surface features of nanoparticles would be electron microscopy or AFM.

Without further details of your application, it's difficult to recommend a specific technique. If the nanoparticles are being used as an electrode, the apparent electrochemical surface area may be all you care about, even though this is not necessarily the same as the geometric surface area.

Comment: But you cannot measure surface area with DLS can you? If I have two equally sized nanoparticles, with a different surface area (i.e. roughness/porosity) I get the same signal from DLS right? Or is there a way to do this?

Comment: @Michiel No, you're right. DLS is looking at mainly size, though you can get some information about shape as well. If he's interested in the surface area of individual nanoparticles, electron microscopy or AFM are going to be the go-to techniques. It may be possible electrochemically, but the apparent electrochemical surface area can be very different from the actual surface area under certain conditions.